# Find two linear transformation $U,T: F^2 \to F^2 $ such that $UT = \mathbf{0} $ but $TU \neq \mathbf{0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Define

$$ T \left( \begin{matrix} x \\  y   \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} x-y \\ y -x \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ U \left( \begin{matrix} u \\  v   \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} u+v \\ -u-v \end{matrix} \right) $$

Then,

$$ UT \left( \begin{matrix} x \\  y   \end{matrix} \right) = U\left( \begin{matrix} x-y \\ y -x \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

however, as can be seen, $TU$ is not the zero transfomation. is this a good choice?

Comment: Define 'good'. Note that this is the same as finding two 2 X 2 matrices A, B such that  AB = 0, but  BA is not 0.

Comment: I mean, if it is correct my solution

Comment: Yes, as shown below, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that you are asking if the solution which you found is correct.

The standard matrix for transformation **T** is
$$\begin{matrix} 1 &-1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix}$$

The standard matrix for transformation **U** is
$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{matrix}$$

**TU** = 
$$\begin{matrix} 2 & 2 \\ -2 & -2 \end{matrix}$$

**UT** = 
$$\begin{matrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}$$

Therefore your choice of matrices answers the question in the title.

Comment: Hi, you mentioned "standard matrix" in your reply. Could you please advise on the exact chapter of undergraduate linear algebra which such questions may fall under? I wish to read futher on these transformations because similar questions tend to pop up rather frequently. Thanks.